# NumberFormatException: Invalid float

Tags: android

My error is :

```
weight = Float.parseFloat(etWeightBMI.getText().toString()); error is (1228): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
```

Comment: what is your question? becuase error is very clear "Need to catch NumberFormatException" or add `null` and number check before calling `parseFloat` method

Answer (score 1):

`etWeightBMI.getText().toString();` returns `blank`. Thats why you get the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Before `Parsing` you should check

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etWeightBMI.getText().toString()))
 {
   //do your job
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line returns null.

```
etWeightBMI.getText().toString();
```

Do this with validation like below:

```
if(etWeightBMI.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
     weight = Float.parseFloat(etWeightBMI.getText().toString());
}
```